# SonarQube multiple Coverage Report types

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, test-coverage

From what I know, there is only one *Coverage* report in SonarQube per project.
Is it possible to **differentiate Coverage Reports by testing source** thus having multiple reports for the same source?
That would be e.g.:

- static code analysis
- Unit-Tests
- End-To-End UI Tests

**Ideal** would be to:

1. tag the coverage data in the build
2. create multiple (dynamic) reports

   - merged from all sources
   - one for each tag

**alternatively** we could assign the coverage data to specific report(s) during the build

**Is there already a solution to implement this?**